# Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain In Github Actions

Tags: gradle, github-actions

I have a simple github workflow to generate my docs which runs gradlew command and it looks like this

```
name: MKDocs
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: 17
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.x

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: pip install mkdocs-material

      - name: Generate Docs
        run: |
          chmod +x ./docs.sh
          chmod +x ./gradlew
          ./docs.sh
```

It gives me an error

[image]

My `gradle-wrapper.jar` file is not being ignored by git

Contents of my `docs.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fail on any error
set -ex

DOCS_ROOT=docs

[ -d $DOCS_ROOT ] && rm -r $DOCS_ROOT
mkdir $DOCS_ROOT

# Clear out the old API docs
[ -d docs/api ] && rm -r docs/api

# Build the docs with dokka
./gradlew dokkaHtml --stacktrace

# Copy README.md to docs
cp README.md ./docs/README.md

# Deploy Docs
mkdocs gh-deploy --force
```

Comment: using `gradle wrapper` command before using tasks command does the trick

Answer (score 2):

I had `/gradle/wrapper` in my .gitignore for some reason, so `./gradlew` would not work in CI, once I added missing directory everything worked just fine